# Percolation in Java

Tags: java

I am having trouble with a percolation program in java using weighted quick union I think there is either a bug in the main where I use union to tell which locations are connected or there is a problem with the test I am running to see if the grid percolates if anyone has some feed back I would appreciate it.

```
/* a class to test for percolation of an N by N grid*/
public class Percolation{
  WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;
  boolean[][] grid;
  public int size;
  int opensites;//keeps track of open sites


 /*Constructor for Percolation that takes N as an argument 
  * to create an N*N grid
  **/
  public Percolation(int N){
    this.size=N;
    int spaces= N*N;
    uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(spaces+1);//initializes the WQUUF data structure.
    opensites=0;//intializes open sites to 0.
    this.grid = new boolean[N][N];// makes a boolean array 2D N by N representing the grid 
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){//i represents the x coordinate
      for(int j=0;j<N;j++){// j represents the y coordinate
        grid[i][j]=false; //sets all spaces as closed
      }//end j loop
    }//end i loop

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      uf.union(size*size,i);
    }// end for that connects all top sites
  }// end constructor;



/*
 * takes to ints as X and Y coordinates 
 * and opens that square on the grid
 **/
  public void open(int i, int j){

    if(!(this.grid[i][j])){
      this.grid[i][j]=true;
      opensites+=1;
    }
  }//end open


/*
 * takes to ints as X and Y coordinates and 
 * returns true if that space is open and false
 * if not
 **/
  public boolean isOpen(int i, int j){
    return grid[i][j];
  }//end isOpen




  /* 
   * takes to ints as X and Y coordinates and 
   * returns true if that space is full and false
   * if not
   */
  public boolean isFull(int i, int j){
    if(isOpen(i,j)){
      if(uf.connected((i+j*size),(size*size))){ return true;}
    }//end for
    return false;
  }//end isFull

  /* 
   * checks if any space on the bottom is full returns true 
   * if there is one false other wise
   */
  public boolean percolates(){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      if(isFull(i,size-1)) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }//end percolates

  /*
   * prints out grid 
   * ---------------------
   * 0 false true false
   * 1 true true true
   * 2 false true true
   * ---------------------
   */
  public void printGrid(){
    StdOut.println("----------------------------------");
    for(int x = 0;x < size;x++){
      for(int y = 0; y < size; y++){
        String mark=isOpen(x,y) ? "x": "0";
        StdOut.print("|"+mark+"|");

      }
      StdOut.println();
    }
    StdOut.println("----------------------------------");
  }


/*
 * Main method takes two int arguments one for the number 
 * of tests to be run and one for the size of the grid
 **/
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tests=StdIn.readInt();
    int size=StdIn.readInt();
    int testedTimes=1;
    int spaces=size*size-1;
    int check=0;
    int space=0;
    while(testedTimes<=tests){
      Percolation perc = new Percolation(size);
      StdOut.println("Before anything");
      perc.printGrid();
      while(!perc.percolates()){
        int x=StdRandom.uniform(0,size);
        int y=StdRandom.uniform(0,size);

        perc.open(x,y);
        space=x+(y*size);
        if((space+1<spaces)&&(x<size-1)){//right 1
          if(perc.isOpen(x+1,y)){
            perc.uf.union(space,space+1);
          }
        }
        if((space-1>0)&&(x>0)){//left 1
          if(perc.isOpen(x-1,y)){
            perc.uf.union(space,space-1);
          }
        }
        if((space-size>0)&&(y-1>0)){//up 1
          if(perc.isOpen(x,y-1)){
            perc.uf.union(space,space-size);
          }
        }
        if((space+size<spaces)&&(y+1<=size)){//down 1
          if((perc.isOpen(x,y+1))){
            perc.uf.union(space,space+size);
          }
          perc.printGrid();
        }

      }//end while(!percolates())
      testedTimes++;
    }//end while(TestedTimes<tests)
  }//end main.
}//end class
```

Comment: I think it's question for CodeReview.

Comment: thanks I just posted it there

Comment: What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: sometimes it says its percolating when it is clearly not and other times it says its not percolating when it is

Comment: I posted this on codereview and they said that they only clean up code and do not help with problems only to clean up coding practices

Comment: Do I get right that you are taking Sedgewick course on algorithms now? So, implementation of WeightedQuickUnionUF is similar to [this](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/WeightedQuickUnionUF.java.html)?

Comment: yes I am taking that course

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you are percolating from left to right and not from top to button (You are using i as column and j as row).

Try to change printGrid, use isOpen(y,x) instead of isOpen(x,y).

Answer (score 1):

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;

public class Percolation {
private boolean[][] grid;
private int len;
private int top = 0;
private int bottom;
private WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;
private int count = 0;

// creates n-by-n grid, with all sites initially blocked
public Percolation(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    len = n;
    grid = new boolean[n][n];
    bottom = n * n + 1;
    uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n * n + 2);
}

// opens the site (row, col) if it is not open already
public void open(int row, int col) {
    if (row < 1 || col < 1 || row > len || col > len) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int i = row - 1;
    int j = col - 1;
    if (!isOpen(row, col)) {
        count++;
        grid[i][j] = true;
        if (row == 1) {
            uf.union(getIndex(row, col), top);
        }
        if (row == len) {
            uf.union(getIndex(row, col), bottom);
        }

        // union the neighbors
        // down
        if (row < len && isOpen(row + 1, col)) {
            uf.union(getIndex(row, col), getIndex(row + 1, col));
        }
        // up
        if (row > 1 && isOpen(row - 1, col)) {
            uf.union(getIndex(row, col), getIndex(row - 1, col));
        }
        // left
        if (col > 1 && isOpen(row, col - 1)) {
            uf.union(getIndex(row, col), getIndex(row, col - 1));
        }
        // right
        if (col < len && isOpen(row, col + 1)) {
            uf.union(getIndex(row, col), getIndex(row, col + 1));
        }
    }
}

// is the site (row, col) open?
public boolean isOpen(int row, int col) {
    if (row < 1 || col < 1 || row > len || col > len) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return grid[row - 1][col - 1];
}

// is the site (row, col) full?
public boolean isFull(int row, int col) {
    if (row < 1 || col < 1 || row > len || col > len) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return (uf.find(getIndex(row, col)) == uf.find(top));
}

// returns the number of open sites
public int numberOfOpenSites() {
    return count;
}

// does the system percolate?
public boolean percolates() {
    return (uf.find(top) == uf.find(bottom));
}

// get the index if row,column
private int getIndex(int row, int col) {
    return len * (row - 1) + (col);
}

// test client (optional)
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to respond, I would write the code for percolation as follows.

I have used the comments to tell what each line and variable is supposed to do.

```
public class Percolation {

// Length of the square grid "gridLength * gridLength"
private int gridLength;

// Array representing indexes of all sites (either it"s open or blocked)
private boolean[] sites;

// Number of open sites
private int openSitesNumber;

// Index of the top virtual site (has value 0)
private int virtualTopIndex;

// Index of the top virtual site (has value (gridLength * gridLength) + 1)
private int virtualBottomIndex;

// Weighted quick union-find data structure
// to calculate percolation
private WeightedQuickUnionUF ufForPercolation;

// Weighted quick union-find data structure
// to calculate fullness (without bottom virtual site)
private WeightedQuickUnionUF ufForFullness;

// Create n-by-n grid, with all sites blocked
public Percolation(int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Grid must have at least one row and column");
    }

    gridLength = n;
    int gridSize = (n * n) + 2; // with two virtual sites
    sites = new boolean[gridSize];
    openSitesNumber = 0;

    // init and open virtual sites
    virtualTopIndex = 0;
    virtualBottomIndex = (gridLength * gridLength) + 1;
    sites[virtualTopIndex] = true;
    sites[virtualBottomIndex] = false;

    ufForPercolation = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(gridSize);
    ufForFullness = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(gridSize);

    // connect top and bottom rows to virtual sites
    for (int col = 1; col <= gridLength; col++) {
        int rowTop = 1;
        int siteTopIndex = getIndexByRowAndColumn(rowTop, col);
        ufForPercolation.union(virtualTopIndex, siteTopIndex);
        ufForFullness.union(virtualTopIndex, siteTopIndex);

        int rowBottom = gridLength;
        int siteBottomIndex = getIndexByRowAndColumn(rowBottom, col);
        ufForPercolation.union(virtualBottomIndex, siteBottomIndex);
    }
}

// Open site (row, col) if it is not open already
public void open(int row, int col)
{
    int siteIndex = getIndexByRowAndColumn(row, col);
    if (sites[siteIndex]) {
        return;
    }

    openSitesNumber++;
    sites[siteIndex] = true;

    // connect with left neighbor
    if (col > 1 && isOpen(row, col - 1)) {
        int siteLeftIndex = getIndexByRowAndColumn(row, col - 1);
        ufForPercolation.union(siteIndex, siteLeftIndex);
        ufForFullness.union(siteIndex, siteLeftIndex);
    }

    // connect with right neighbor
    if (col < gridLength && isOpen(row, col + 1)) {
        int siteLeftIndex = getIndexByRowAndColumn(row, col + 1);
        ufForPercolation.union(siteIndex, siteLeftIndex);
        ufForFullness.union(siteIndex, siteLeftIndex);
    }

    // connect with top neighbor
    if (row > 1 && isOpen(row - 1, col)) {
        int siteLeftIndex = getIndexByRowAndColumn(row - 1, col);
        ufForPercolation.union(siteIndex, siteLeftIndex);
        ufForFullness.union(siteIndex, siteLeftIndex);
    }

    // connect with bottom neighbor
    if (row < gridLength && isOpen(row + 1, col)) {
        int siteLeftIndex = getIndexByRowAndColumn(row + 1, col);
        ufForPercolation.union(siteIndex, siteLeftIndex);
        ufForFullness.union(siteIndex, siteLeftIndex);
    }
}

// If site (row, col) open
public boolean isOpen(int row, int col)
{
    int siteIndex = getIndexByRowAndColumn(row, col);

    return sites[siteIndex];
}

// If site (row, col) full
public boolean isFull(int row, int col)
{
    int siteIndex = getIndexByRowAndColumn(row, col);

    return (isOpen(row, col) && ufForFullness.connected(virtualTopIndex, siteIndex));
}

// Number of open sites
public int numberOfOpenSites()
{
    return openSitesNumber;
}

// If the system percolate
public boolean percolates()
{
    // if grid with one site - check if it"s open
    if (gridLength == 1) {
        int siteIndex = getIndexByRowAndColumn(1, 1);
        return sites[siteIndex];
    }

    return ufForPercolation.connected(virtualTopIndex, virtualBottomIndex);
}

// Get site"s index to be represented in array
private int getIndexByRowAndColumn(int row, int col)
{
    validateBounds(row, col);

    return ((row - 1) * gridLength) + col;
}

// Check if row and column values are in range of grid size
private void validateBounds(int row, int col)
{
    if (row > gridLength || row < 1) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Row index is out of bounds");
    }

    if (col > gridLength || col < 1) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Column index is out of bounds");
    }
}

// Test client (optional)
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Percolation percolation = new Percolation(2);

    StdOut.println("percolates = " + percolation.percolates());

    StdOut.println("isOpen(1, 2) = " + percolation.isOpen(1, 2));
    StdOut.println("isFull(1, 2) = " + percolation.isFull(1, 2));
    StdOut.println("open(1, 2)");
    percolation.open(1, 2);
    StdOut.println("isOpen(1, 2) = " + percolation.isOpen(1, 2));
    StdOut.println("isFull(1, 2) = " + percolation.isFull(1, 2));
    StdOut.println("numberOfOpenSites() = " + percolation.numberOfOpenSites());
    StdOut.println("percolates() = " + percolation.percolates());

    StdOut.println("isOpen(2, 1) = " + percolation.isOpen(2, 1));
    StdOut.println("isFull(2, 1) = " + percolation.isFull(2, 1));
    StdOut.println("open(2, 1)");
    percolation.open(2, 1);
    StdOut.println("isOpen(2, 1) = " + percolation.isOpen(2, 1));
    StdOut.println("isFull(2, 1) = " + percolation.isFull(2, 1));
    StdOut.println("numberOfOpenSites() = " + percolation.numberOfOpenSites());
    StdOut.println("percolates() = " + percolation.percolates());

    StdOut.println("isOpen(1, 1) = " + percolation.isOpen(1, 1));
    StdOut.println("isFull(1, 1) = " + percolation.isFull(1, 1));
    StdOut.println("open(1, 1)");
    percolation.open(1, 1);
    StdOut.println("isOpen(1, 1) = " + percolation.isOpen(1, 1));
    StdOut.println("isFull(1, 1) = " + percolation.isFull(1, 1));
    StdOut.println("numberOfOpenSites() = " + percolation.numberOfOpenSites());
    StdOut.println("percolates() = " + percolation.percolates());
}
```

}

Comment: could you elaborate why do you need a separate `ufForFullness`? Why can't  just use `ufForPercolation` in  `isFull()`. which problem `virtualBottom` does make?

Comment: @dehasi when percolation occurs, all components that contain an open
cell in the bottom row are declared “full” (and will be visualized as such), because they are
connected through the dummy bottom row to an actual full cell in the bottom row

Comment: API update: The method 'connected' is deprecated. Instead, we must use the method 'find' to check if both components are connected to a same root.